# Update the a scope value after the $index hit a certain number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm repeating some items using `ng-repeat`, but when the `$index` hit a certain number I want to change the `$scope` after that number.

So let's say: I have a `ng-repeat` and I have this attribute:

```
ng-attr-cy="{{ team1.cy }}"
```

and this in my controller `$scope.team1.cy = 30;`

What I want is when the `$index > 8` it changes the value of the scope to something like `$scope.team1.cy = 100` for the items after 8.

I just can't come up with a solution, I would say something like how the `ng-if` works but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="number in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]" ng-init="$index > 8 ? team1.cy = 100 : ''">
</div>
```

`ng-init` will be invoked at each iteration where we can check if the `$index` reaches 8 then we are incrementing the number.

**Update**

Looking at your codepen example, it is clear that we can not directly alter the `team1.cy` variable to update it to 100 after `$index` reaches 8.

So unless you want to use the variable `team1.cy` somewhere else, you can fix your problem like this:

```
<circle ng-repeat="person in team1.members"
    class="dotMap"
    ng-click="mapCurrentPerson($event)"
    fill="#232323" stroke="#232323"
    stroke-miterlimit="10"
    ng-attr-cx="{{$index * 40 + 40}}"
    ng-attr-cy="{{ cyValue }}"
    ng-init="cyValue = ($index > 8 ? 100 : 30)"
    r="16.5"
    ng-class="{selectedMap: current.name === person.name}" />
```

If the expression in your `ng-init` is getting complex then I would suggest you writing a function in your controller scope like this:

```
$scope.calculateCyValue = function($index) {
    return  ($index > 8 ? $index * 40 + 40 : $index * 40 + 40);
};
```

And then use it in your HTML (now you don't need the `ng-init`):

```
<circle ng-repeat="person in team1.members"
    class="dotMap"
    ng-click="mapCurrentPerson($event)"
    fill="#232323" stroke="#232323"
    stroke-miterlimit="10"
    ng-attr-cx="{{$index * 40 + 40}}"
    ng-attr-cy="{{ calculateCyValue($index) }}"
    r="16.5"
    ng-class="{selectedMap: current.name === person.name}" />
```

Comment: Ah I see but when I hit the 8+ items all the items have the new value  of 100. Let's say I have 10 items and the first 8 need to have 30 and the last 2 need to have the value of 100, that is the result I wanna achieve. And thanks for the edit of my spelling ^

Comment: Are you passing that attribute `ng-attr-cy` to the same element or to the child of the element in which your `ng-repeat` is added?

Comment: Wow, awesome didn't knew this was possible this way. Thanks alot

Comment: So but how would you tackle a thing like
ng=init="cxValue = ($index > 8 ? $index * 40 + 40 : $index * 40 + 40". If I want to start the x value again from the value of 40 when the index hits 8. But since the index is already 8 on that point you automatically start the math with a 8 already so. Codepen for example: http://codepen.io/denniswegereef/pen/dGMYgY

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass on the index to a method on your vm and return the desired value from there:

```
ng-attr-cy="{{vm.getValue($index)}}"

vm.getValue = function(index){
   // do some magic with the index.
   return myData[index];
}
```